# Hide clear text password in nuget.config from source control

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, nuget, github-actions

I have a `nuget.config` file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycompany/index.json" />
    </packageSources>

    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="username" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="password" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>

    <packageSourceMapping>
        <packageSource key="github">
            <package pattern="MyCompany.*" />
        </packageSource>

        <packageSource key="nuget.org">
            <package pattern="*" />
        </packageSource>
    </packageSourceMapping>
</configuration>
```

This file is checked in to source control and includes the clear text password. I don't want the password to be visible in source control. I use GitHub Actions for building the project. Is it possible to use a secret/env variable to replace the password?

Comment: That could be solved with simple string replacement. You can replace "password" with a distinct placeholder e.g. `__CLEARTEXT_PASSWORD__` and then depending on your GHA runner's shell, you can use its command line utilities to replace it e.g. `sed`, `envsubst`, etc. on Linux and Powershell has its utilities to handle XML.

Comment: @Azeem I'm not the person who wrote the original question, but this will break the local machine development experience.

Comment: @zivkan: Depends on the local build flow. However, the Option 2 i.e. fetching directly from the env var seems a much better alternative.

Comment: Using a dummy value that is commit into the repo means for local development they have to change the value locally and force git to ignore the change, or otherwise take care not to accidentally stage/commit the file when committing other changes. Using an environment variable means locally they have to locally save their token in an env var with the same name, and unless they have a special script to set the env var only when doing .NET development, it will make the env var available to all processes running as that user account.

Comment: Therefore, I disagree that using an env var is the best alternative. Putting the credential in a user-profile nuget.config allows encrypted credentials to be saved on disk on Windows (and later MacOS, when we eventually add Mac KeyChain support). Whereas the env var exposes secrets in clear text to all processes, not just NuGet, even encrypted secrets are available on the platform.

Comment: @zivkan: I was referring to the Option 2 of your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77264238/7670262). Given the OP's requirements i.e. GHA workflow and clear text, that seems to be the right approach.

Comment: Something I notice some people do is hyperfocus on the problem at hand, and come up with solutions that have bad side effects in other scenarios, because they didn't consider them. Yes, the question was about GHA workflows, but that doesn't mean the best overall solution (taking into account local development experience) is the one that sounds easiest to enable GHA workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: credentials in user-profile nuget.config

As [NuGet's docs on its config files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) states, NuGet reads multiple nuget.config files and "accumulates" them.

Therefore, you can have your repo nuget.config contain the `<packageSource>` and `<packageSourceMapping>` sections, but move the `<packageSourceCredentials>` to your user-profile nuget.config (or another nuget.config in the parent directory of your repo, so it's not in source control), and this way your repo nuget.config won't have any credentials saved in it

### Option 2: Use environment variable substituion for the credential value

[The docs for nuget.cofig's `packageSourceCredentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials) has a few examples, and the second of which shows using a `%name%` substituion to get the value from an environment variable. For example:

```xml
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="username" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%EnvironmentVariableName%" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Automatic token authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) which handles the secret management for you by substituting `${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` where your password goes.

If you use this token in your GitHub Actions Workflows, it won't break local development because that is totally separate.

Please read [Security hardening for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions) for more information.